# Word 2013 XML Mapping

Tags: xml, word-2013

How to maintain an existing xml mapping using Word 2013?

I have the following xml mapping:

[image]

How can edit one of the nodes or add another node to this exiting xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need help with this.

I found this video: [Creating a Custom XML part in Word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrriThs7m1s)

And i used this tool to edit the word xml: [Open XML Package Editor for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b)